# My website looks too big on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I have this site here `paoladi.com` and the it looks weird on iPhone and iPad...if I increase the height on the wrapper div, its fixes my problem, but then I am stuck with a ton of white space. What would be the best way to do this? I am thinking I will have to create a new css for iphone and another for ipad and use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to detect if they are using an iphone and ipad and style my site? It sounds like it will take awhile..is there a better way to do this?

Comment: check responsive css with media queries. It is much better to target screen size then user agent!

Comment: Your best bet is definitely to go with @media queries.  This link may be helpful for for pointing you in the right direction and getting comfortable with media queries.  http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Also, check out a framework like Bootstrap which has tons of built in functionality that is ready to plug and play.  http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/